# mongodb connection issue on openshift after update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift

I am experimenting with a nodejs service on openshift that connects to a Mongodb database at mongolab. I am using mongoose to connect to the database.
Everything worked great until mongolab updated to version 3.0 of mongodb. Everything still works if I run the services locally but I am getting an authentication error in the logs trying to connect to the database. From the research I have done it sounds like the driver my openshift gear is using is not compatible with Mongodb 3.0. How should I correct this in my openshift area ?
Thanks a lot .....

Comment: Have you tried to specify a newer version of the node.js mongodb driver in your package.json.?

Comment: Thank you, this solved it.I set mongoose to the latest version, 4.1.10 and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the updated version of the mongodb driver on your package.json, i.e.:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": ">=4.1.10"
  }
}
```